# Expected number of points in a cubic volume given a GMM

Tags: matlab, 3d, gaussian, cdf

I have a 3D space which I discretized in voxels (cubes of volume). I also have a set of 3D points in such space. I want to know the expected number of points in a given voxel. I chose  GMM as a model for this purpose, but I do not know how to calculate what I want starting from mu, sigma and weight of each Gaussian.

So far I managed to fit the GMM (easy):

```
obj = gmdistribution.fit(points', 20);
```

and I to plot it via

```
figure(1);
hold on;
for i = 1:k
    plot_gaussian_ellipsoid(obj.mu(i,:), obj.Sigma(:,:,i));
end
axis equal;
```

which results in what I expect, that is a map where the colors tell me the concentration of points.

The question is, how can I extract the expected number of points in a voxel, given its center `(x,y,z)` and its side `s`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use (see example here http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/gmdistribution.cluster.html)

```
idx = cluster(gm,points);
```

Comment: I do not understand how that answers my question. Could you be more explicit?